# Просмотр триггера, созданного с опцией WITH ENCRYPTION

Tags: sql-server

Всем привет.
Подскажите, как можно просмотреть код триггера,созданного с опцией WITH ENCRYPTION на удалённом сервере SSMS2012? [Тут](http://www.t-sql.ru/post/Encryption.aspx) нашёл как это сделать с помощью [DAC](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators) и сторонней SP. Есть ли внутренний инструмент для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Подсказывают на англоязычном StackOverflow стандартными средствами просмотреть нельзя. Как вариант можно использовать встраиваемые утилиты, например [ApexSQLComplete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) , в ней используем Alter объекта и в description видим код.